# Testcontainers with a company proxy

Tags: java, docker, http-proxy, testcontainers, docker-java

Each start of different testcontainers will throw `com.github.dockerjava.api.exception.InternalServerErrorException: {"message":"Get https://quay.io/v1/_ping: dial tcp x.x.x.x: getsockopt: connection refused"}`

This is no surprise (docker is behind a company proxy). How can I configure testcontainers to use a specific HTTP proxy?

Another approach could be disabling the "ping" command and using our company docker repo.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can by specifying env variables when you are building an image or running a container. For example, below I'm building an Elasticsearch container by passing proxy configuration:

```
GenericContainer container = new GenericContainer("docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:6.1.1")
            .withExposedPorts(9200)
            .withEnv("discovery.type", "single-node")
            .withEnv("HTTP_PROXY", "http://127.0.0.1:3001")
            .withEnv("HTTPS_PROXY", "http://127.0.0.1:3001")
            .waitingFor(Wait.forHttp("/_cat/health?v&pretty")
                    .forStatusCode(200));
```

Otherwise, you can set your proxy settings globally in docker. For windows with a docker machine you have to connect to it and the HTTP proxy in `boot2docker` profile.

```
docker-machine ssh default

sudo -s

echo "export HTTP_PROXY=http://your.proxy" >> /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
echo "export HTTPS_PROXY=http://your.proxy" >> /var/lib/boot2docker/profile
```

On Linux, you can create a file `~/.docker/config.json` like :

```
{
 "proxies":
 {
  "default":
  {
    "httpProxy": "http://127.0.0.1:3001",
    "noProxy": "*.test.example.com,.example2.com"
  }
 }
}
```